# android studio 3.2 Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, gradle-dependencies, android-appcompat

I am using android studio 3.2 and I installed android studio 2.2 before using this one. When I open a new project I get these errors I mentioned below. I want to mention again that I didn't make any change on layouts or main.activity. I have checked the solutions for old versions but the problem still exist. Here is what I have tried before:

changing apply plugin: 'com.android.application' to apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
- Unchecking offline mode.
- Adding repositories :

```
mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
```

- changing appcompat to older versions (v7:26+ or v7:25)
Here are the logs of the errors :

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
Open File
Show Details
```

--> My gradle.wrapper.properties

```
#Thu Sep 27 09:39:31 EET 2018
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists zipStoreBase\=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10-all.zip
```

--> My build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.a26033623.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

--> build.gradle(project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I am truly struggling for 2 days browsing the solutions, and I really feel lost. Thanks for your time, attention and your help in advance.

Comment: Try with buildToolsVersion "27.0.3".

Comment: @FaysalAhmed I tried it and resulting error is:
The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (27.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.0.
Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.2 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
Update Build Tools version and sync project
Open File

Comment: @FaysalAhmed Minimum build tools for AGP 3.2.0 is 28.0.3. Read here: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin The error message says 28.0.2 but the link also explains why 28.0.3 is safer.

Comment: Hi @UgurKonak are you solved this one?

Comment: Hi @Sakthi the only way to solve this problem was uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio as I explained in my comment below. But from my experiences, I can say that switching between different internet connections may solve this problem too. If you are using a network in your office try using your home network. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way**

1) Android Studio `3.1.4`

2)

```
COMPILE_SDK_VERSION=26
BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=27.0.3
TARGET_SDK_VERSION=26
```

3)

> build.gradle{project}

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

}
```

4) support library version should be same you can use `26.1.0` for above configuration, for Example `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0`

5) and final step is

> gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

Comment: I tried it and I get this error this time: "Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

Comment: put log here, what the exactly you have facing!

Comment: By the way, you mean that I should download 3.1.4 with your first step, right ? Because I downloaded 3.1.4 first and then tried your settings

Comment: yes because 3.1.4 is the only stable version available in market, 3.2 has released but with sum bugs. for further refer : https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/

Answer (score 0):

I deleted all files related to "Android Studio" including .gradle files and SDK files. Then I installed Android Studio 2.2.1 and it worked. What I encountered may be about the remainings of Android 2.2.1. I am not sure but maybe I should have deleted everything about Android Studio before installing the new version.
Now, I am using version 2.2.1. I hope it helps to someone who will try to upgrade his/her Android Studio to a newer version.